# Lack of step-notifications in cucumber-junit-platform

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

How can I set showing of test steps using Cucumber and JUnit 5(cucumber-junit-platform-engine)?

Previosly, with JUnit 4 it was possible by adding Cucumber Option stepNotifications = true

```
@CucumberOptions(
stepNotifications = true,
strict = true,
features="path to feature file",
glue="path to step definition file")
```

It is highly recomended to use junit-platform.properties in JUnit 5, but I was unable to find there corresponding property: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#configuration-options

Comment: See this: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/2471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as with JUnit 4, the domain of JUnit 5 does not have anything to express sub-test steps.

While it would theoretically be possible to represent steps as individual tests this would result in various other issues such as miscounting executed tests, misreporting failures, complications executing in parallel, etc as seen with JUnit 4.

Detailed answer: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/2471

Comment: add context around the link

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CucumberOption `junit = "--step-notifications"` to show the individual steps.

```
@CucumberOptions(
   junit = "--step-notifications"
   strict = true,
   features="path to feature file",
   glue="path to step definition file")
```